# How do I get past this Python OpenTimelineIO installation problem?

Tags: python, pycharm, python-import, requirements.txt

I am attempting to write a quick Python test program, to test out the OpenTimelineIO library. I want to start with the sample code found in [in the library's sample code, here](https://github.com/PixarAnimationStudios/OpenTimelineIO/blob/master/examples/summarize_timing.py)

I'm using PyCharm on Windows, and installed OpenTimelineIO by adding the following to my `requirements.txt` file and then getting PyCharm to handle the installation:

`cmake==3.17.2
OpenTimelineIO==0.12.1`

The modules report having installed successfully in the virtual environment, but as soon as I add the following reference in my code:

`import opentimelineio as otio`

I am getting the following error message (paths shortened with [...]):

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "[...]/func_aaf.py", line 3, in <module>
    import opentimelineio as otio
  File "[...]\venv\lib\site-packages\opentimelineio\__init__.py", line 35, in <module>
    from . import (
  File "[...]\venv\lib\site-packages\opentimelineio\opentime.py", line 1, in <module>
    from . _opentime import ( # noqa
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.`

The error is being thrown on the first line of one of the OpenTimelineIO's .py files, when it tries to import some classes:

`from . _opentime import ( # noqa
    RationalTime,
    TimeRange,
    TimeTransform,
)`

I don't understand the syntax of the punctuation in "from . _opentime" and can't find references to RationalTime or TimeTransform within the code. I suspect I'm misunderstanding how the library is meant to be installed, or how I'm supposed to add the library; either that, or I need to make an adjustment to the import code within OpenTimelineIO.

Pointers for how the library can import RationalTime etc. would be much appreciated.

Comment: RationalTime and TimeTransform are defined in cpp bindings that looks like to be build at install time. Error is actually saying that it failed to load _opentime dll..  If you installed from tar file instead of wheel and you dont have working compiler, installation really did fail .. You could also check what dll's are in your venv .. maybe copying those into venv/bin folder might help too ..

Comment: I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling opentimelineio, cmake and wheel, both through PyCharm's management of requirements.txt, and though command line pip install commands- still getting the same result. There is an "opentime.dll" file within site-packages\opentimelineio\cxx-libs\ - are you suggesting I need to copy it somewhere? (There is no bin folder within my venv folder.)

Comment: Further to this, it appears that if I install OpenTimelineIO version 1.11.0 it works OK, but the more recent versions 0.12.0 and 0.12.1 have this issue. I'll try and find an OpenTimelineIO forum to discuss it.